# PHP for-loop with integer

Tags: php, for-loop

I start learning PHP(beginners) and got some trouble with for-loop. Need to Create a **for-loop** that iterates from 0 to (including) 16. Add the integer value for each iteration to a string and separate each item with a "," (comma). Neet answer with the final string without an ending ",".

So long i came.

```
 <?php
$string = "";
for ($x = 0; $x <= 16; $x++) {
    $string=$x ",";
} 
echo $string;
?>
```

Sorry guys for your time.

Have nice day !

Comment: Just look at   http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Have a look [at the manual about for-loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and try something. If you get stuck on something specific while trying, come back, show us what you've tried, where you're stuck and we can help you from there. SO is not a substitute for doing research and practice. It should be the last resort after you've exhausted all other options.

Comment: `rtrim` comes to mind or just a conditional in the loop to see if you are at the last value. Showing your code and where you are hung up would help.

Comment: I was starting with that but the problem i got is how can i add  integer value for each iteration to a string and separate each item with a ","

<?php 
for ($x = 0; $x <= 16; $x++) {
    echo " $x <br>";
} 
?>

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you've tried instead of posting it as a comment. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There's also a much easier way of doing this than using a for-loop: `echo implode(',', range(0, 16));`. Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/Li2Vn

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I need to use for loop. Can you check code above please? Added code on the top.

Comment: You've already got a couple of answers that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

**METHOD 1**

```
$output = implode(',', range(0,16));  
echo $output;   //0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

**Breakdown: From inside out**
The `range()` function is used to create an array (from 0 to 16) and then the `implode()` function is used to join the elements of the array using what we call a glue and in our case that glue is a `,`.

**METHOD 2 - FOREACH LOOP**

This could be done using the traditional `for` loop but I always favor the `foreach` loop because it has a cleaner syntax and it's easier to understand.

```
<?php
    $arr = range(0,16);  //Create an array from 0 - 16
    $output = "";       //Create an empty string to store the ouput
    foreach($arr as $item){   //Loop through each item of the array
        $output .= $item.',';   //Concatenate a comma to the current item and assign it to the output
    }

    echo rtrim($output, ',');   //trim the last comma to the right using `rtrim()` and then `echo` the output  //0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

?>
```

**METHOD 3 - FOR LOOP**

```
<?php

    $output = "";

    for($i = 0; $i <= 16; $i++) {
        $output .= $i.',';
    }

    echo rtrim($output, ',');
?>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation why the OP should use this, what problem it solves and how it solves it. Also, if you're using `range()`, why would you use a loop at all?

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but i need to do it only with for loop. Check code above on the top.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ...Damn! Your second question made me rethink my solution. How did I miss that. Thanks. I have added comments to my code.

Comment: @Mattis ... Compare your code with my `for` loop to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Mattis ... First, you are not concatenating properly and you are not trimming the last comma.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `trim()` after completion of concatination

```
$string = "";
for($i =0; $i<=16;$i++)
{
   $string.=$i.",";
} 
$string = trim($string,",");
echo $string;
```

You can also get same result by single line of code as follows-

```
echo implode(",", range(0, 16));
```

Comment: Can you please check my code above on the top what I doing wrong please?

Comment: you forgot to put `'.'` operator to concatinate, you wrote `$string=$x ",";` inside loop, instead you should have `$string.=$x.",";` and then trim your string

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the comma when (`if`) `$x` is not the last number in the "loop":

```
<?php

$string = "";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 16; $x++) {
    $string .= $x;
    if ($x != 16 ) {
        $string .= ",";
    }
}

echo $string;
```